# NSData on custom class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth, nsdata

I am about to look into bluetooth interaction on the iPhone. Now, i read that the only object that can be transferred is an NSData object. Now, i wanna transfer my "character" objects. The class looks something like this:

```
@interface Character : NSObject <NSCoding>
{
   UIImage *characterImage;
   int health;
   NSString *name;
}

-(void) initWithStats;
-(void) addToViewController: (UIViewController *)theView;

-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;
-(void) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder;

@end
```

Now, i know that i have to conform to the NSCoding protocol and implement those 2 methods, however, i am not quite sure what to do here. I know i somehow need to be able to make instances of this class and then "unpack / unarchieve" them when the NSData object is received by the other device.

So, any advice here is greatly appreciated :=) i am very new to bluetooth programming and have never worked with that or the NSData before. So thanks on advance :)

/JBJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're really just asking how to implement `-encodeWithCoder:` and `-initWithCoder:`. It's pretty straightforward:

```
-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:characterImage forKey:@"character image"];
    [encoder encodeInt:health forKey:@"health"];
    [encoder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
}
```

That's all. `-initWithCoder:` works exactly the same way, except you call the complementary methods, such as: `characterImage = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"character image"];`.

If you need to provide the data in a particular format to work with the target device that doesn't support the archive format, you can do that instead and use the `-encodeBytes:length:forKey:` method to store whatever you like, or write data in your own format into a NSMutableData object and then use `-encodeObject:forKey:` on that. Your target device may still need to find your data in whatever envelope the encoder stores it; you can make that easier by starting with a known series of bytes. I'm not sure whether that's necessary in your case, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Wow, that actually sounds pretty straight forward. So this NSData is actually holding several objects all packed together, and then this NSData object is transferred via bluetooth, and the other device will "unpack" the NSData object and start working with the objects it contained? i got it or? thanks again chap.